# Define API routes in ZF3 having more than one parameters

Tags: rest, api, routes, zend-framework3

I wanna create an API route in zend framework 3 that has two parameters. I have defined my routes as follows:

```
'api' => [
    'child_routes' => [
    /* api/users/<id> */
    'users' => [
        'type'    => Segment::class,
        'options' => [
            'route'       => '/users[/[:id]]',
            'constraints' => [
                'id' => '[0-9]+',
            ],
            'defaults' => [
                'controller' => Api\Controller\UserController::class,
            ],
        ],
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes' => [
            /* api/users/<uid>/documents/<id> */
            'documents' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'       => '/documents[/:id]',
                    'constraints' => [
                        'id'   => '[0-9]+',
                    ],
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Api\Controller\DocumentController::class,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]
    ]
]
```

The routes I expects to be supported are:

```
api/users
api/users/<user_id>
api/users/<user_id>/documents
api/users/<user_id>/documents/<document_id>
```

Following above rules, when I send an HTTP Get to api/users//documents, it refers to method "get" in "DocumentsController.php", while it is expected to call method "getList".

The question is how should I change my routes, and is my resource definition follows API design principals?

Comment: I would agree with your general expected route setup. I don't with the optional parameter before required parameters though. `api/users//documents` works as intended because the user id parameter is optional. I would suggest you create a required child route `/:id` for the single user. Give that the child construction for documents. Mind: you can always have more than one route go to the same endpoint, so you could do: `/api/users/id/documents` but also: `api/documents` and have both use `DocumentController::class->index` function (and then handle (not) having an id in the function)

Answer (score 0):

You should also add action name, you can add your action name along with controllers.
So, controlls will be goto to "getList" for "api/users/documents" and "index" "api/users"

As in below updated code:

```
'api' => [
    'child_routes' => [
    /* api/users/<id> */
    'users' => [
        'type'    => Segment::class,
        'options' => [
            'route'       => '/users[/:id]',
            'constraints' => [
                'id' => '[0-9]+',
            ],
            'defaults' => [
                'controller' => Api\Controller\UserController::class,
                 'action'    => 'index',
            ],
        ],
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes' => [
            /* api/users/<uid>/documents/<id> */
            'documents' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'       => '/documents[/:id]',
                    'constraints' => [
                        'id'   => '[0-9]+',
                    ],
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Api\Controller\DocumentController::class,
                        'action'    => 'getList',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]
    ]
]
```